# Most comprehensive, foolproof way to determine available features in .NET MF 4.1?

Tags: .net-micro-framework

I'm just starting to learn the .NET Micro Framework, and coming from C# I have quickly realized (and can certainly understand why) several classes are not available in the MF.  The tricky part for me is actually determining what the available features are.  It would be great if there was a webpage where I could type in something that I want, and it would tell me if it's available, and if not, what the closest match is.

For example, if I wanted a `List<T>`, maybe it would tell me to use an `ArrayList`.  Or it would suggest a `Hashtable` instead of `Dictionary`.

I usually google, or hope that MSDN will point me in the right direction.  However, today I wanted to use `System.Nullable`, and it was apparently not available.  I couldn't find an appropriate assembly to add from the Add References dialog.  Google failed me as well, and when I went to check `System.Nullable` at MSDN, I couldn't find references to the .NET MF anywhere.

So I am basically assuming at this point, that `System.Nullable` isn't available, but for those trying to do some .NET MF development, is there a better way to quickly ascertain whether or not a particular class is okay to use?

Comment: `Nullable` isn't available because it relies on Generics, which aren't part of the micro framework.

Comment: @Eric thanks, good point.  I should have realized that when List<T> wasn't available as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've likely found answers to this by now.  In case others arrive here:

[Jan Kučera](http://informatix.miloush.net/microframework/Articles/CisFeatures.aspx) has a list of what's available on Netmf as far as main features are covered.  Version 4.1 and 4.2 are mostly similar to 4.0 as far as C# language goes (note: 4.2 adds VB) see [Netmf blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netmfteam/archive/2011/10/04/version-4-2-rtm.aspx) for the release info. General documentation is [on Codeplex](http://netmf.codeplex.com/documentation) and [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc533014.aspx) has the class list.  I generally use the .chm help file that accompanies the micro-framework as a starting point what what classes and more important what methods/properties are included in netmf.  There are a small number of places where the docs don't jibe with the actual classes, so the best bet is to fly it and see if the compiler salutes it. otherwise ask on the netmf forum: [www.netmf.com](http://www.netmf.com)

Comment: thanks, although I have found the info I needed in different places, I like the links you have shared.